# React double installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react app. When I run the development server I get the following error (sorry that it is an image):

[image]

here is the code for the ONE component that I am using (besides `BrowserRouter`):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";

require("react-dom");
window.React2 = require("react");
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);

export default function SignUp() {
    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        username: "",
        password: "",
        email: "",
        phone: ""
    })
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    function updateForm(value) {
        return setForm((prev) => {
            return {...prev, ...value}
        })
    }

    async function onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newUser = {...form}

        await fetch("http://localhost:5000/account/add", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newUser)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            window.alert(error);
            return;
        })

        /*
        setForm({
            username: "",
            password: "",
            email: "",
            phone: ""
        })
        */
       
        navigate("/")
    }
    return (
    <div>
     <h3>Sign In</h3>
     <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
       <div className="form-group">
         <label htmlFor="name">Username</label>
         <input
           type="text"
           className="form-control"
           id="name"
           value={form.name}
           onChange={(e) => updateForm({ username: e.target.value })}
         />
       </div>
       <div className="form-group">
         <label htmlFor="position">email</label>
         <input
           type="text"
           className="form-control"
           id="position"
           value={form.position}
           onChange={(e) => updateForm({ email: e.target.value })}
         />
       </div>
       <div className="form-group">
         <label htmlFor="name">Phone Number</label>
         <input
           type="text"
           className="form-control"
           id="name"
           value={form.name}
           onChange={(e) => updateForm({ phone: e.target.value })}
         />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
         <label htmlFor="name">Password</label>
         <input
           type="text"
           className="form-control"
           id="name"
           value={form.name}
           onChange={(e) => updateForm({ password: e.target.value })}
         />
        </div>
       <div className="form-group">
         <input
           type="submit"
           value="Sign Up"
           className="btn btn-primary"
         />
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>
    )
}
```

I am completely stumped as to what could be causing this.

One more thing, the `false` at the top of the image is because I added a check to see if the react installation used by `index.js` is the same as the one used by the component file as recommended in the react docs. It comes out to `false` which leads me to believe there are different installations being used.

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: That can’t be the one component you’re using because the error occurs inside BrowserRouter and there isn’t a BrowserRouter in that component. Start at the entry point of your application - where you first call createRoot or reactdom.render - and remove all the components inside that one until your error goes away, then start adding them back

Comment: @Adam sorry, I meant the one component besides built in ones. I will edit the question.

Comment: Where is window.React1 defined? Also, should you be importing useNavigate from react-router-dom by any chance?

Comment: @Adam window.React1 is defined in index.js but I added it after I started getting errors. I will try changing were that is imported from. EDIT: changing were usenavigate is imported from did not fix the errors.

Comment: Blow away your node modules, reinstall, get rid of all the lines you’ve added to “debug”, and start from your root node and have it render no components, then, add them back one at a time and narrow down where the actual error is coming from. Is this a create-react-app?

Comment: @Adam yes, it is

Comment: @Adam thank you so much for the help!!!!!!! turns out the error was with BrowserRouter, which was not installed so npm was probably using an installation from some different location in my file system, I installed it in the root directory of the react app and now it is working! Would you please post an answer so I can accept and upvote?